# how to view contacts in iphone in simulator

Tags: iphone

hai i'm new to iphone programing
how to view contacts in iphone in simulator?
ok. my question in detail is,
my application runs on simulator. my app should access contacts information of iphone when iphone is connected to mac(pc).

Comment: are you saying you want to do this to debug your application, or is this how you want your app to work when other people use it?

Answer (score 1):

You can't access the contacts stored off of the device. The user will have to sync the contacts either with iTunes or Exchange to the device.

Comment: You can access the device contacts .But one this you can try is to add contacts in your simulator .

Answer (score 0):

You can access to contact list if you login to iCloud in simulator.